# How to communicate with OneShotRunner

Tags: rust, yew

I try to pass a calculation from Yew App to a Worker via `OneShotRunner`.
I cannot however seem to figure out how to communicate between App and Worker.
Naively I have this code:

```rust
pub enum Msg {
    SetResult(String)
}

pub struct Foo {
    input: String,
    result: String,
}

impl Component for Foo {
    type Message = Msg;
    type Properties = ();

    fn create(_ctx: &Context<Self>) -> Self {
        Self {
            input: "[]".into(),
            result: "[]".into(),
        }
    }


    fn update(&mut self, _ctx: &Context<Self>, msg: Self::Message) -> bool {
        match msg {
            Msg::SetResult(result) => {
                self.result = result;
                true
            }
        }
    }

    fn view(&self, ctx: &Context<Self>) -> Html {
        let bar_task = use_oneshot_runner::<BarTask>();

        let on_bar = ctx.link().callback(|_e: MouseEvent| {
            spawn_local(async move {
                // This does not work
                let o = bar_task.run(input).await;
            });
            Msg::SetResult(o)
        });

        html! {
            <main>
                <OneshotProvider<BarTask> path="/worker.js">
                    <button onclick={on_bar}>{ "Bar" }</button>
                </OneshotProvider<BarTask>>
            </main>
        }
    }
```

Would be great if someone could point out how normally this needs to be connected.

Comment: "_This does not work_" → **What** doesn't work? Does it fail to compile? With what error? Does it compile but fail to run? With what error? Does it compile and run but fail to produce the expected result? What did you expect and what happened instead?